# Problem related to classical mechanics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, notation, density, moment-of-inertia

[image]

The actual formula for density is mass/volume. Can someone explain how this $dm = p.dx$ came?

Comment: It's the linear mass density. It's more commonly denoted by $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just looks like $\rho$ is a *linear* density, not a *volumetric* density:

$$\text{mass}=\text{lineic density}\times\text{length}$$

I'm not a fan of formal calculations mixing up symbols and numerical values, it makes formulas difficult to parse...